# A gstreamer pipeline using decodebin with rtsp uri works on Ubuntu amd64 but fails on Ubuntu arm64 on raspberry pi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I'm running this gstreamer pipeline:

```
GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.101:554/Streaming/Channels/301 ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=10 ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! fakesink
```

On Ubuntu 22.04 amd64 and gstreamer 1.20.3, the pipeline succeeds. On a raspberry pi running Ubuntu 22.04 and gstreamer 1.20.3, the same pipeline fails.

Previously, the raspberry pi had ubuntu 20.04 and the pipeline worked. The failure started after the upgrade to ubuntu 22.04 and gstreamer 1.20.3.

**Output on Ubuntu 22.04 amd64**

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Prerolled, waiting for progress to finish...
Progress: (connect) Connecting to 
rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.101:554/Streaming/Channels/301
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
0:00:00.132555538 1850580 0x55909562c5e0 WARN                  udpsrc 
gstudpsrc.c:1637:gst_udpsrc_open:<udpsrc0> warning: Could not create a buffer of 
requested 524288 bytes (Operation not permitted). Need net.admin privilege?
0:00:00.132717085 1850580 0x55909562c5e0 WARN                  udpsrc 
gstudpsrc.c:1647:gst_udpsrc_open:<udpsrc0> have udp buffer of 212992 bytes while 
524288 were requested
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Redistribute latency...
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Redistribute latency...
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:43.659785576
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

in the above case the pipeline succeeds.

**Output on Ubuntu 22.04 arm64 on a Raspberry Pi 4B**

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Prerolled, waiting for progress to finish...
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.101:554/Streaming/Channels/301
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
0:00:00.152446203 18369 0xaaaaff7285e0 WARN                  udpsrc gstudpsrc.c:1637:gst_udpsrc_open:<udpsrc0> warning: Could not create a buffer of requested 524288 bytes (Operation not permitted). Need net.admin privilege?
0:00:00.152683647 18369 0xaaaaff7285e0 WARN                  udpsrc gstudpsrc.c:1647:gst_udpsrc_open:<udpsrc0> have udp buffer of 212992 bytes while 524288 were requested
0:00:00.154342329 18369 0xaaaaff7285e0 WARN                  udpsrc gstudpsrc.c:1637:gst_udpsrc_open:<udpsrc1> warning: Could not create a buffer of requested 524288 bytes (Operation not permitted). Need net.admin privilege?
0:00:00.154515958 18369 0xaaaaff7285e0 WARN                  udpsrc gstudpsrc.c:1647:gst_udpsrc_open:<udpsrc1> have udp buffer of 212992 bytes while 524288 were requested
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Redistribute latency...
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Redistribute latency...
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
Redistribute latency...
0:00:02.308668148 18369 0xffff88019120 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2229:gst_v4l2_object_get_streamparm:<v4l2h264dec0:src> VIDIOC_G_PARM failed
0:00:02.311433716 18369 0xffff88019120 WARN                GST_CAPS gstpad.c:5757:pre_eventfunc_check:<src_0:proxypad6> caps video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1 not accepted
0:00:02.311557827 18369 0xffff88019120 WARN                GST_CAPS gstpad.c:5757:pre_eventfunc_check:<src_0:proxypad6> caps video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1 not accepted
0:00:02.311601604 18369 0xffff88019120 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4351:gst_pad_peer_query:<v4l2h264dec0:src> could not send sticky events
Redistribute latency...
0:00:02.317580833 18369 0xffff88019120 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:842:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:<v4l2h264dec0:pool0:src> Uncertain or not enough buffers, enabling copy threshold
0:00:02.335438925 18369 0xaaaaff728b00 WARN                GST_CAPS gstpad.c:5757:pre_eventfunc_check:<src_0:proxypad6> caps video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1 not accepted
0:00:02.336078832 18369 0xaaaaff728b00 WARN                GST_CAPS gstpad.c:5757:pre_eventfunc_check:<src_0:proxypad6> caps video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1 not accepted
0:00:02.336312979 18369 0xaaaaff728b00 WARN                GST_CAPS gstpad.c:5757:pre_eventfunc_check:<src_0:proxypad6> caps video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1 not accepted
0:00:02.345931830 18369 0xffffac031cc0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc1> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:02.346106996 18369 0xffffac031cc0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc1> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:02.162084024
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
0:00:02.360763688 18369 0xaaaaff7285e0 WARN                 default gstrtspconnection.c:1362:writev_bytes: Operation was cancelled
0:00:02.360882169 18369 0xaaaaff7285e0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:6607:gst_rtspsrc_try_send:<source> error: Could not send message. (Received end-of-file)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source: Could not write to resource.
Additional debug info:
../gst/rtsp/gstrtspsrc.c(6607): gst_rtspsrc_try_send (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Could not send message. (Received end-of-file)
0:00:02.361226928 18369 0xaaaaff7285e0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:9034:gst_rtspsrc_pause:<source> error: Could not send message. (Received end-of-file)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source: Could not write to resource.
Additional debug info:
../gst/rtsp/gstrtspsrc.c(9034): gst_rtspsrc_pause (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Could not send message. (Received end-of-file)
Freeing pipeline ...
```

In the above case, the pipeline fails.
Why is the pipeline failing on the Pi and what can I do to remedy it?